# Is there a way to check that a given family $\mathcal{F}$ of continuous functions at $x_0$ is equicontinuous at $x_0?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_X), (Y,d_Y)$ be two metric spaces.

Let $\mathcal{F}\subset C(X,Y)$ be a family of continuous functions, each of them continuous at $x_0\in X.$ I'd like to **get a sufficient condition on the family $\mathcal{F}$** to guarantee that $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous at $x_0\in X.$

One immediate condition is that $\mathcal{F}$ is finite. Is there any other? One would like to guess that the compactness of $\mathcal{F}$ in a suitable topology of $C(X,Y)$ (one can assume $X$ compact if necessary, but other topologies are also fine) might help us achieve equicontinuity of $\mathcal{F},$ but I can't manage to prove anything in that direction. Is there such a theorem or perhaps such an exercise that asks us to show something similar? Resources or proofs appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for [Arzela-Ascoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces)? Besides, a sufficient condition is that all functions are Lipschitz continuous with bounded Lipschitz constant.

Comment: @Klaus Thanks, not Arzela Asocli , that extracts a uniformly convergence subsequence. I'm trying to see if the compactness of the family of the functions in some suitable topology alone can help us go from continuity to equicontinuity.

Comment: Arzela-Ascoli implies that $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous if it is compact in the compact-open topology. If that's not what you want, you might want to specify.